# Multiple Different Sized Annotations on Single MKMapView Map

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've an iPhone app that shows users locations on a map and the goal is that the size of the marker is proportional to the popularity of the location. More popular places get a slightly larger annotation.

I've a custom MKAnnotation and MKAnnotationView to display markers. I've tried to use the custom MKAnnotationView to render the different sized markers, but the same sized images are always rendered.

Here's the class.

Any advice or suggestions are welcome:

```
#import "MapAnnotationView.h"

@implementation MapAnnotationView

- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
MapAnnotation * myAnnotation = (MapAnnotation *) annotation;
self = [super initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

// Figure out if in 'normal' mode or 'compare' mode
// normal
if (myAnnotation.visited != nil) {
    if ([myAnnotation.visited boolValue] == YES) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"visited.png"];
    } else if ([myAnnotation.visited boolValue] == NO) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unvisited.png"];
    }
// compare
} else {

    // On both maps
    if ([myAnnotation.onLoggedInUsersMap boolValue] == YES && [myAnnotation.onComparisonMap boolValue] == YES) {
        if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] == 1) {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"both_small.png"];
        } if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] < 5) {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"both_medium.png"];
        } else {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"both_large.png"];
        }
    // Only on comparison's map
    } else if ([myAnnotation.onLoggedInUsersMap boolValue] == NO && [myAnnotation.onComparisonMap boolValue] == YES) {
        if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] == 1) {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compare_small.png"];
        } if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] < 5) {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compare_medium.png"];
        } else {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compare_large.png"];
        }
        // Only on owner's map
    } else {
        if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] == 1) {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"owner_small.png"];
        } if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] < 5) {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"owner_medium.png"];
        } else {
            self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"owner_large.png"];
        }
    }
}
return self;
}

@end
```

And here's the viewForAnnotation method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    if ([annotation class] == MKUserLocation.class) {
        return nil;
    }

    MapAnnotationView *aView = [[MapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"location"];
    [aView setEnabled:YES];
    [aView setCanShowCallout:YES];
    aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    return aView;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether execution reaches the mapCount logic in the init method?  Does it show the right mapCount?  Show the viewForAnnotation method.  How is mapCount set and is it ever updated after annotation is added to the map?

Comment: Yes: the mapCount logic is working (NSLog's placed within each if statement print the correct totals and update correctly as the map is panned). The mapCount is a property of each MKAnnotation object; it's set by a call to the server and does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is three missing `else`'s in the big conditional in the init method:

```
// On both maps
if ([myAnnotation.onLoggedInUsersMap boolValue] == YES && [myAnnotation.onComparisonMap boolValue] == YES) {
    if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] == 1) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"both_small.png"];
    } else if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] < 5) {  // <----------------
      // ^-- was missing else before the if
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"both_medium.png"];
    } else {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"both_large.png"];
    }
    // Only on comparison's map
} else if ([myAnnotation.onLoggedInUsersMap boolValue] == NO && [myAnnotation.onComparisonMap boolValue] == YES) {
    if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] == 1) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compare_small.png"];
    } else if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] < 5) {  // <----------------
      // ^-- was missing else before the if
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compare_medium.png"];
    } else {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compare_large.png"];
    }
    // Only on owner's map
} else {
    if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] == 1) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"owner_small.png"];
    } else if ([myAnnotation.mapCount intValue] < 5) {  // <----------------
      // ^-- was missing else before the if
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"owner_medium.png"];
    } else {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"owner_large.png"];
    }
```

---

Two separate, unrelated issues are:

- memory leak in `viewForAnnotation` because it is not releasing `aView`
- should be using `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` in `viewForAnnotation`

So the `viewForAnnotation` method should look like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    if ([annotation class] == MKUserLocation.class) {
        return nil;
    }

    MapAnnotationView *aView = (MapAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"location"];
    if (!aView)
    {
        aView = [[[MapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                      reuseIdentifier:@"location"] autorelease];
        [aView setEnabled:YES];
        [aView setCanShowCallout:YES];
        aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }
    else
    {
        aView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return aView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much; this worked.I had to make a slight change to the if/else logic of the viewForAnnotation method you propose: my MapController allows the user to toggle different states of the map (code not shown). I added a refresh method to the MapAnnotationView that I call after the aView.annotation = annotation line and it calls all of the presentation logic in MKAnnotationView to ensure the right image is shown.